# Как сделать из цифр пирамиду?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать из цифр пирамиду?

Вот собственно код:

```
<center><script> 
for (var i=1; i<=29; i++) 
{ 
    document.write(' '+i+' '); 
    if (i%5>=4) {document.write('<br>');}; 
}; 
</script></center>
```

Только не пишите заумными кодами :). Я прошел всего лишь

- `confirm`
- `prompt`
- `var * = prompt`
- `for`
- `alert`
- `document.write`
- `переменные`

Comment: Какие-то условия есть? вида, к-тво цифр, строк и т.д.?

Answer (score 4):

Никакой заумности, чистая логика:

```js
for(var i = 1;i <= 29; ++i) 
{
 for(var j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
  document.write(' '+j+' '); 
 document.write('<br>'); 
};
```

И неважно что вы прошли. Всегда надо идти дальше.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// пирамида из цифр
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) { //рисуем строки
  for (let n = i; n < 10; n++) { // рисуем пробелы
    document.write("&nbsp"); 
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < i; k++) { // рисуем цифры
    document.write(k); 
  }  
  document.write(" <br/>")
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! Обратите внимание - у нас на сайте есть возможность оформлять скрипты так, что их можно сразу на сайте быстро запустить и проверить работу (Я вам поправил сообщение, чтобы было видно). Рекомендую, удобная штука.

Comment: Оратор выше забыл упомянуть что для этого есть специальная кнопочка в тулбаре в блоке для написания ответа

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужно чтобы каждая строка начиналась с первого числа, а просто подряд шли числа, то можно так:

```js
const maxNum = 92;
let str = '';
let numsCountInRow = 1;

for (let i = 0, k = 0; i < maxNum; ++i) {
  str += ` ${i + 1}`;
  ++k;
  
  if (k % numsCountInRow === 0) {
    ++numsCountInRow;
    document.write(str + '<br>');
    str = '';
    k = 0;
  }
}

document.write(str);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Но как видно, этот метод при отсутсвии нужного количества элементов, создаёт "ножку у ёлки"